# Qual a diferença entre um web service no mesmo projeto e um projeto diferente na mesma solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-service, wcf, organização-de-projeto

Todos me dizem para criar um REST e não SOAP. Sei que só vou pegar bem isso fazendo.

Peguei um projeto antigo na empresa em que eu estou com um *web service* no mesmo projeto.

Como estou usando MVC, fui criar um *web service* e me deparei com duas situações: ou eu começo um novo *web site* (Um novo projeto na *solution*); ou eu adiciono um novo item (WCF) e crio um *web service* (WCF) no mesmo projeto.

Confesso não conseguir distinguir bem essa diferença, se é que existe. O que realmente devo fazer? Existe uma forma certa ou mais vantajosa em usar uma abordagem sobre a outra?

Comment: A solution é apenas um agrupador logico de projetos, que o Visual Studio utiliza, é similar (não igual) ao workspace do Eclipse;

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Cria uma projeto Class Library do seu negócio
2. Crie um projeto MVC 4 ou 5 para seu Site
3. Crie um projeto MVC/WebAPI para seu WebService REST
4. No seu projeto de Site e Web Service faça referencia ao seu Projeto de negócio (1)

Comment: Não tenho a opção de Class Library. Eu dou um Add na solution e não me vem a opção de Class Library

Comment: @pnet qual é o seu IDE? VS 2012 Web ?

Comment: 2012 e 2013, mas em um outro forum um amigo me disse que Class Library é windows form e não web, por isso eu não estava encontrando.

Comment: Não é Windows Form,  E class library, distinto, um projeto desse tipo gera uma dll que pode ser usada por qualquer outro tipo de projeto .NET

Answer (score 2):

Se você for criar serviços REST, eu recomendo fortemente em usar [WebAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh833994%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Os conceitos são parecidos com os do ASP.NET MVC, tendo controllers e actions... e portanto é mais fácil de reutilizar seus conhecimentos.

Você pode criar no mesmo projeto, não tem necessidade de iniciar um projeto novo, a não ser por motivos de organização.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar esse serviço REST usando **WCF** ou **WebAPI**, ambas tem suas peculiaridades.

Porém uma questão interessante também é sobre a publicação:

Criando um novo projeto separado do seu projeto Asp.Net MVC, sempre que o seu projeto Asp.Net MVC e o seu serviço REST forem alterados e houver necessidade de atualizá-los em ambiente de produção, você precisa publicar cada um. Atualizando dois projetos.

Já criando o serviço REST no seu projeto Asp.Net MVC, sempre que você for publicar a sua aplicação, não será necessário publicar também o seu serviço REST. Atualizando apenas o projeto Asp.net MVC.